# sqlalchemy noForeignKeys error with association class and relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am getting an error with my sqlalchemy relationship.  This relationship is modelled as an association object.  Upon compile, I get the following error:

> ```
> "specify a 'primaryjoin' expression." % self.prop) sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError:
> ```
>
> Could not determine join condition
>   between pa rent/child tables on relationship
>   Entries.users_who_have_read_this - there are n o foreign keys linking
>   these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associ ated with a
>   ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expre
>   ssion.

```
class UsersReadArticles(alchemyDB.Model):
    '''
    '''
    __tablename__ = 'users_read_articles'
    id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    article_id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('entries.id'))
    date_read = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.DateTime)

class Entries(alchemyDB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'

users_who_have_read_this = alchemyDB.relationship('UsersReadArticles',
                                                  foreign_keys = [UsersReadArticles.user_id],
                                                  backref = alchemyDB.backref('users_who_have_read_this', lazy = 'joined'),
                                                  lazy = 'dynamic',
                                                  cascade = 'all, delete-orphan')

class User(UserMixin, alchemyDB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_email = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you share UserMixin? I am trying simulate the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your problem is that the SqlAlchemy could not initialize target column for ForeignKey 'entries.id' on table 'users_read_articles', because the table 'entries' has no column named 'id'

Second, in mapper users_who_have_read_this have a mistake: You don't need define a foreign key to column 'user_id' on table UsersReadArticles. It's enough set a foreing key only on UsersReadArticles in this case.

So, I suggest some changes like that:

```
class UsersReadArticles(alchemyDB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users_read_articles'
    id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    article_id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('entries.id'))
    date_read = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    user = alchemyDB.relationship("User", backref="usersreadarticles") 

class Entries(alchemyDB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(255))
    users_who_have_read_this = alchemyDB.relationship('UsersReadArticles',
                                                  backref = alchemyDB.backref('users_who_have_read_this', lazy = 'joined'),
                                                  lazy = 'dynamic',
                                                  cascade = 'all, delete-orphan')

class User(alchemyDB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_email = alchemyDB.Column(alchemyDB.String(64), unique = True, index = True)
```

Testing:

```
e = Entries()
e.title = 'Article 1'
alchemyDB.session.add(e)

u = User()
u.user_email = 'dedeco@gmail.com'
alchemyDB.session.add(u)
alchemyDB.session.commit()

r = UsersReadArticles()
r.user_id = u.id
r.article_id = e.id
alchemyDB.session.add(r)
alchemyDB.session.commit()

u = User()
u.user_email = 'xpto@gmail.com'
alchemyDB.session.add(u)
alchemyDB.session.commit()

r = UsersReadArticles()
r.user_id = u.id
r.article_id = e.id
alchemyDB.session.add(r)
alchemyDB.session.commit()
```

Result:

```
>>> art = alchemyDB.session.query(Entries).all()
>>> for a in art:
...     print a.title, "Who read:"
...     for u in a.users_who_have_read_this:
...         print u.user.user_email
... 
Article 1 Who read:
dedeco@gmail.com
xpto@gmail.com
```